# Jekyll errors when starting the server

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, jekyll, octopress

I'm running Octopress/Jekyll on Ubuntu.

When I do the following command:

```
$ bundle exec rake generate preview
```

I get the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/liquid-2.5.5/lib/liquid/htmltags.rb:43: 
warning: key "index0" is duplicated and overwritten on line 46
Configuration file: /home/alex/Code/octopress/_config.yml
        Source: source
   Destination: public
  Generating... 
jekyll 2.0.0 | Error:  undefined method `extname' for 
#<Jekyll::StaticFile:0x00000003482d78>
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.0'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'octopress-hooks', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'octopress-date-format', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'pygments.rb'
  gem 'maruku'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'
```

Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved these errors by updating my Gemfile to:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 10.0'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'octopress-hooks', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'octopress-date-format', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.6.3'
  gem 'jekyll-paginate'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4.2'
```

Note that my pygments.rb gem doesn't seem to work properly - it doesn't highlight the code syntax according to language (i.e. Ruby): it just changes the font family and keeps it in a bland grey colour (instead of highlighting in Ruby colours).

But that's another issue.
For now, the initial errors - at least - are resolved.